# docker image running not able to access api in spring boot gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle

I have created a image of spring boot gradle project by using command `gradlew jibDockerBuild`

I run the image by this command `docker run -p 8082:8082 demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.Image is running successfully on port 8082.In project application.properties server.port is 8082 only.

I am not able accesss api so I have checked in my machine whether this process is running on the port or not by command `netstat -a -n -o | find "8082"`.No process is running on that port.

Comment: do you see your docker process running using docker ps command?

Comment: @sam3131 yes its running

Comment: can you rerun your netstat command with sudo and check if it appears? docker may run with privilegied access

Comment: I am using windows machine

Comment: Can you try http://192.168.99.100:8082 in windows machine browser

Comment: @MyTwoCents Its working with that ip.Can I know the reason?

Comment: @MyTwoCents I have done port mapping. why need to access with docker machine ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Docker on Windows by `Docker Toolbox` by default `Docker` will run on `192.168.99.100` IP (DOCKER_IP).

You can access all your containers running inside docker with DOCKER_IP on your Host machine ie Windows.

Read more on it [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-use-localhost-instead-of-192-168-99-100/54098)

Regarding your mapping query

You have mapped port, which means your container port will be mapped to `DOCKER_IP:PORT`

If you were using Docker on Linux or Mac it will get mapped to `localhost:port` as in those cases Docker is running on localhost.

The same is not true for Windows at least with Docker Toolbox.

As per your configuration, you can access your application on `HOST` machine by hitting

```
http://192.168.99.100:8082
```

Comment: Today again I tried this url http://192.168.99.100:8082  but the site is unreachable and image is running successfully.please refer the link once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847404/docker-host-is-not-running