# Docker host is not running

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using windows 7 machine.I installed docker toolbox having version 19.03.5.When I try to fetch docker machine ip am getting error

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker-machine ip
Error getting IP address: Host is not running
```

So when I check the docker status `docker-machine status default` it shows stopped.I tried to start using `docker-machine start default` getting error

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Somet
imes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error setting up host only network on machine start: C:\Program Files\Oracle\Vir
tualBox\VBoxManage.exe modifyvm default --nic2 hostonly --nictype2 82540EM --nic
promisc2 deny --hostonlyadapter2 VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2 --cabl
econnected2 on failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code E_FAIL (0x80004005) - Unspecified error (extended in
fo not available)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at lin
e 529 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

I am able to run docker commands.

When I run the command docker-machine ip on docker Quick start terminal it showing ip(192.168.99.100).When I hit the ip getting unreachable.I able am to run the docker image also when I try to access the resources present in that getting unreachable.

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like some network issue with Virtual Box for `default` VM used by Docker.

Try following steps

- Open virtual box, stop default and remove it
- Right-click Docker Quickstart, select run as administrator

It will setup `default` VM again in Virtual Box

Refer [this](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/291) for more detail

**Note:** You will lose all existing Docker Images if any.

**Edit 1:**

As per screenshot attached. Port needs to be exposed in order to make it accessible from Host machine.

```
docker run -p 9999:8082 nithin4325/demo
```

You can access it on `192.168.99.100:9999`

Assuming `8082` is your spring Application port configured and you want to access it to `9999` port on the host.

Assuming `9999` port is available on the host (no application is running on that port) else might throw **Port already in use** error

Comment: I tried what you said I am able to get ip now in dokcer quickstart terminal,command prompt but not in git bash command prompt.I tried to access docker machine ip and also resources of a running image in chrome getting not reachable.

Comment: When you run docker through docker quickstart terminal.  docker will be available only in that Terminal.  It's not available globally So can't access from git bash .  That will work for Docker for Windows

Comment: But yesterday I am able to access from git bash also.Now eventhough I am able to get ip from quickstart start terminal but not able access docker machine ip and also resources of a running image in chrome getting not reachable

Comment: Its better you go one step at a time.  First, check if your docker quickstart terminal starts Docker successfully as i suspect just by getting ip doesn't mean docker is running. . you can run "docker run hello-world" to check if its working fine.  If it doesn't work you need to resolve this issue. regarding git bash  As you said it was working yesterday in git bash it should work fine now.

Comment: I am able to run docker run hello-world.I got message also as Hello from Docker! This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

Comment: ok. Good.  What is "resources of a running image" which you cant access.  its any application deployed in container w

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206457/discussion-between-nithin-and-mytwocents).